# Windows 10 sleeping after 2 minutes

Tags: windows

I've been searching for an answer for 2 weeks and have pursued all the OS power settings including shutting off 'quick start'.  I use a remote key board and monitor along with a few other USB loads.  I have unhooked everything back to the basic HP Envy x360 laptop and the problem remains. I've reset all the power settings to default as well as the BIOS.  Ready to throw in the towel and go back to Windows 7.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? "sleeping after 2 minutes" - even when working? Sleeping = standby?

Answer (score 0):

After a Windows 10 update, a new power setting was introduced... which on many systems defaulted to two minutes. To make this setting visible, in the *Power Options* dialog select *Choose what the power buttons do*.

[image: Power Options dialog]

In the *Power Options > System Settings* dialog, *Change settings that are currently unavailable*.

Turn on *Sleep* and *Hibernate* "show in power menu".

[image: Power Options > System Settings* dialog]

Now go back to *Power Options*, *Change plan settings* for the active plan, and go through each item to check for that two minute default timeout.